# problem in preparing where clause of an update method in c#

Tags: c#, sql

hey guys, i'm finding little difficult to prepare a where clause in following update method
i'm creating a update method, here am i doin' this in a rightway ? but still m confused that how do i know that which property is to use in where clause

or any better approach to create a generic update method ? i wud be very thankfull

**EDIT**

```
    public bool UpdateData(object Entity, ref String error)
    {
        Type objectType = Entity.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = objectType.GetProperties();
        error = "";
        string column = null;
        int i = 0;
        SqlConnection conn = OpenConnection();
        SqlCommand sqlcommand=null;
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                i++;
                continue;

            }
            column += (i >= 0 && i < properties.Length - 1) ? string.Format(@"{0}=@{0},", info.Name) : string.Format(@"{0}=@{0}",info.Name);
            i++;
        }
        try
        {
            string sqlQuery = string.Format(@"update {0} set {1} 
            where {2}='{3}'", objectType.Name, column,1,1);//see here m not getting how to prepare this where clause
            sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
            i = 0;
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;

                }
                sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(string.Format("@{0}", info.Name), info.GetValue(Entity, null));
            }
            sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlcommand = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection(conn);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

see in above code there is an if condition `if (i == 0)` in `foreach loop` i dont want to do this way coz here i'm assuming my objects `property i.e employee_id` is at 1st index in array of `PropertyInfo[]`.. what if some one makes a class properties like `public string employee_name{get,set} public string employee_add{get,set} public string employee_id{get,set}` in this case the `foreach loop` will skip `employee_name` instead of 'employee_id' coz i used `if(i=0)`, i want a way to skip only identity value i.e `employee_id` in `foreach loop in my update function` irresptive of its index in `propertyInfo` array..... did i explained well ?

Comment: use SQLCommand Parameters, rather than string.Format()

Comment: Ooh, that is SQL-injection heaven! Seriously: that is very unsafe code

Comment: i have edited my code now my question is how do i prepare where clause ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom attribute or an interface to determine the property that represent the id of your entity and use it in your where clause. Although this approach has a negative side that you have to change your entity classes (which is not always possible).
Here's an example :

```
[PrimaryKey]
public string EmployeeId
{
get;set;
}
```

or

```
public class Employee:IEntity
{
public object EntityId
{
get
{
return this.EmployeeId
}
}
}
```

another way might be to store the entities metadata somewhere else (a xml file or a dictionary for example)

for example:

```
<entities>
<entity type="Employee" primarykey="EmployeeId" />
</entities>
```

or

```
Hashtable EntityPrimaryKeys=new Hashtable{(typeof(Employee),"EmployeeId")};
```

Comment: thanx a ton, Attributes will do for me... but for that i need to do this right `object[] properties = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);` i wonder is there any method to get attribute by name, coz `info.getCustomAttributes` return an array but i want only 1 property..

Comment: As far as I know that's the only way to get custom attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You really should use SQLCOmmand.Parameters instead of concatenating strings int he sql.
That way it will be more readable, secure and more feature proof.
You have a classical query exploit in your code where somebody could send in a parameter containing '; drop database yourdatabase; select * from dual where ''=' or similar.

So please update your code and if you have the same issue we will see what's going on.

Comment: Simic: hi, i have edited my code and used `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add()` method, now my question is how do i prepare where clause ??

Comment: @FosterZ could you provide the final SQL you wish to achieve so i can take a look?

Comment: see, m getting column names and their values using reflection.. now i want to create update statement but my problm is to prepare where clause of the update statement, for e.g i have `class employee` and properties as `employee_id,employee_name,employee_add` so to create a update statement using reflection i get `update employee set column_names_with_values_by_reflection where ?=?` see in where clause i want `eployee_id=some_value`... m sry that m not able to explain clearly....

Comment: you can add and employee_id=@employee_id to the where clause and then add another parameter, @employee_id to the command

Comment: i guess, i failed to express my problem clearly, please have a look i edited my question, below the code...